# Copying duplicates into new table - Old MySQL version complicates

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1136

Due to an older version of MySQL I'm having to use some pretty outdated methods to get things done.
At the moment I am trying to copy similar rows to another table based on a few distinct columns. The table `holddups` will be taking data from `assets` where the SKU and Description match those of one in `holdkey`. The command I'm running is:

```
INSERT INTO holddups
SELECT * 
FROM assets, holdkey
WHERE assets.SKU = holdkey.SKU
AND assets.Description = holdkey.Description
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

I hope this is enough to sort this all out, but if not feel free to ask more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting just `*` will take all columns from `assets` and `holdkey` and try to put it in `holdups`. But `holdups` does not have that much columns. Using `assets.*`will only take all columns of `assets` and that is what you want, right?

```
INSERT INTO holddups
SELECT assets.* 
FROM assets, holdkey
WHERE assets.SKU = holdkey.SKU
AND assets.Description = holdkey.Description
```